# How to create an object using JNI which has a implied default constuctor

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

[I've tagged C++ too since that's what I'm using to implement the JNI].

I'm trying to create an instance of a Java class: `foo` say. But it doesn't have an explicit default constructor. But it has no other explicit constructors either, so therefore a default constructor *does* exist, just implicitly.

How can I call it using `env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");`? I've already found `foo` via `env->FindClass`: `cls` is not zero.

Presumably my arguments are incorrect but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Oops. Just figured this out. Sorry to waste time!

Answer (score 3):

Use `env->GetMethodID` instead with exactly the arguments you passed.

Using `env->GetStaticMethodID` to create an instance is meaningless.